# Why is there increase in p-value even with increase in correlation b/w dependent and independent variables: logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, logistic

I am working on loan prediction data set.

### Here is what the structure looks like:

```
'data.frame':   614 obs. of  12 variables:
$ Gender           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Female","Male": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Married          : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Dependents       : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","1","2","3+": 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 4 3 2 ...
$ Education        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Graduate","Not Graduate": 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
$ Self_Employed    : Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
$ ApplicantIncome  : num  8.01e+33 8.92e+32 1.97e+31 5.12e+30 1.01e+34 ...
$ CoapplicantIncome: num  0.00 5.17e+12 0.00 3.09e+13 0.00 ...
$ LoanAmount       : int  138 128 66 120 141 267 95 158 168 349 ...
$ Loan_Amount_Term : int  360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 ...
$ Credit_History   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
$ Property_Area    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Rural","Semiurban",..: 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 ...
$ Loan_Status      : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
```

---

Next, took 2 specific variables (  ApplicantIncome, CoapplicantIncome both continuous) and transformed the variables to cube and square form resp.
As can be seen below (refer column transf cor), the  cor has improved after applying transformation.

```
      transformation type          initial cor           transf cor
 1                cube              -0.004709523         -0.05599575
 2              square              -0.059187313         -0.08069006
```

Finally, compared logistic model coeff and p-values before and after transformation, for predicting variable loan_status using all other variables.
Following is the summary (showing only applicantIncome and coapplicant values here):

After transformation:

```
                         Estimate      Std.Error      z value      Pr(>|z|)    
   ApplicantIncome       -8.736e-45     3.528e-44      -0.248      0.80444    
  CoapplicantIncome      -1.953e-18     3.809e-18      -0.513      0.60817
```

Before transformation:

```
                        Estimate      Std. Error     z value       Pr(>|z|)    

   ApplicantIncome      6.160e-06      2.740e-05       0.225       0.822099    
  CoapplicantIncome    -5.801e-05      3.700e-05      -1.568       0.116945
```

What i do not understand is that for CoapplicantIncome when the cor has improved, shouldn't the coeff and p-value improve (i.e. decrease) as well?

Comment: I have edited in the original question..

Comment: What is your cor value showing the correlation between? ApplicantIncome and CoapplicantIncome?

Comment: correlation is between loan_status and applicant income, loan_status and co-applicant income.. loan-status being the dependent variable